# How does current get reduced in resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

How does the resistor reduce the current? I know that when there is no resistor in the circuit the current is higher than the current when there is a resistor.

But, my question is:
How the resistor reduces current from the starting of the path of current, i.e. from the point where the connecting wire is connected to the positive terminal of the battery. Current must get reduced after reaching the starting point of the resistor. For a better understanding of the question, I have added the image of a simple electric circuit.

[image]

Comment: Resistor converts electric energy to hear energy.

Answer (score 4):

> But, my question is: How the resistor reduces current from the
> starting of the path of current, i.e. from the point where the
> connecting wire is connected to the positive terminal of the battery.

It doesn't. The current is the same in the resistor and the connecting wires.

You can't think of current as as something where electric charge makes a journey from one battery terminal to the other encountering different series resistance along the way causing the current to increase or decrease.

Charge, generally in the form of mobile or free electrons, is already present in the circuit components (wiring and resistors) before the battery is even connected to the circuit, i.e., when the switch is open. Upon closing the switch an electric field is established at nearly the speed of light throughout the circuit. The force due to the field causes all the mobile electrons to move simultaneously.

In order for charge to be conserved, the same amount of charge has to simultaneously leave one battery terminal and enter the other. This means the rate at which charge crosses a given point anywhere in the series circuit, which is the definition of current, has to be the same, otherwise charge would have to "build up" somewhere in the circuit. Adding or removing resistance only decreases or increases the magnitude of the current throughout the circuit for a given applied voltage.

So we know that the current in the connecting wires and in the resistor has to be be the same due to conservation of charge. But we also know it is harder to move the charges through the resistor than the connecting wires. So if the same amount of charge per second needs to be moved through the resistor as through the connecting wires, more work per unit charge is required to move the charge through the resistor than the wires.

The work $W$ required per unit charge $Q$ to move the charge between two points equals the potential difference, or voltage $V$, between the two points, or

$$V=\frac{W}{Q}$$

You may recall that the general definition of work is force times distance, or

$$W=\vec F.d\vec l$$

Now, the force $\vec F$ that does the work to move the charge $Q$ the distance $d\vec l$ is supplied by the electric field $\vec E$ and equals, for a constant field

$$\vec F=Q\vec E$$

Substituting the last equation into the second

$$W=Q\vec E. d\vec l$$

Substituting into the first equation

$$V=\frac{Q\vec E. d\vec l}{Q}$$

$$V=\vec E. d\vec l$$

Since the direction of the electric field is the same as the current flow

$$E=\frac{V}{l}$$

Finally, since the voltage drop per unit length of the resistor is greater than the voltage drop per unit length of the connecting wire, it tells us that the magnitude of the electric field has to be greater in the resistor than the connecting wires.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If there is electric field , then current must get accelerated

Comment: No. Though I didn't include it, the force exerted by the field is opposed by the equal force of the resistance in the wires and resistor for a net force of zero therefore resulting in constant drift velocity of the electrons. It's like you pushing a box at constant velocity on a floor with an equal opposing kinetic friction force.

Comment: Sorry mr Bob , but can u explain me how the current next to the battery terminal adjust itself according to resistor. Because resistor is far from battery terminal

Comment: But opposition of resistance and wire are different then how can they oppose electric field. Sorry if I sound stupid and annoying , but I can't find answer of my questions

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari. what electrical classes have you taken and at what level?

Comment: I am in 10th grade

Comment: Mr Bob , pls reply

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari Check out the answers here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/how-do-electrons-know-to-share-their-voltage-between-two-resistors. In particular, look at dmckee's answer under the sub heading "how do electrons know". See if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The resistor is a component that impedes the flow of current. If, in your circuit, the resistor was replaced by a wire, then a much larger current would flow (even wires have a small and non-zero resistance).

As noted, current isn't smaller in different parts of the resistor.

But if the question is about how a resistor works, a (very) simple model is as follows: Think about a large number of people starting off from zero speed at the start of an empty tunnel, each with a blind fold on, and directed towards the other end of the tunnel.

With nothing to impede the runners, some might hit the walls but the general motion would be in the forward direction, the runners reaching potentially reaching large speeds.

Now place a few obstacles in the way. If the runners hit these objects they will be momentarily stopped and have to start running from zero speed again so that the average speed of the runners through the tunnel gets a little smaller.

As you increase the number of obstacles, so the mean speed of the runners will get slower and slower.

If you attach the same electric charge to each runner, then with no obstacles and the runners reaching large speeds, the number of charges passing some point in unit time would be larger. With obstacles in the way, the numbers of charges passing some point is smaller. Electric current is just amount of charge passing a point in unit time.

Answer (score 1):

In the steady state of the circuit, the current before and after a resistor must be equal, because if there is a difference in current, there is a build up of charge inside the resistor that will go on forever. So the current next to the battery adjusts itself according to the resistance of the resistor.

Comment: How will current next to the battery adjust itself

Comment: The dynamics of the process are analyzed with waves of current and moving from the battery to the resistor and back, where the first wave has a current which depends on the wire, and each back and forth gets close and closer to the steady state solution. You will learn this when you study transmission lines

Comment: Pls explain in detail