# How do charge carriers "know" how much voltage to use for work in a specific component?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I understand the basic concepts of voltage pretty well, I think. However, one thing has been bugging me which I can’t seem to figure out.

How does a specific charge carrier "know" how much voltage to use as work in a specific component?

As an example, say a bulb of resistance $10\ \Omega$ and an EMF of $12\ V$. As expected, the bulb will "use up" all of that $12\ V$ and convert it to light and thermal energy. However, say another $5\ \Omega$ bulb is added in series. How does the charge carrier know not to use all $12\ V$ on the first $10\ \Omega$ bulb, but rather $8\ V$ to save $4\ V$ for the other one?

Or, as another example, with a potential divider, how do the charge carriers know how much voltage to "drop off" at the $100\ \Omega$ resistor (in the diagram below), before they reach the potentiometer?

[image: Simple potential divider with a potentiometer and 100 ohm fixed resistor]

I understand that voltage is a potential energy, and so it’s just a measure of where in the electric field it is, but does this mean adding a component or adjusting the potentiometer, etc. changes some property of the field? Or am I misunderstanding voltage entirely?

Comment: FWIW: The charge carriers (valence electrons in metal conductors) in your 12V light bulb circuit move more slowly than a garden snail. Imagine a switch that shorts out your second resistor, effectively removing it from the circuit when the switch is closed. Imagine opening the switch. The "news" that the resistor suddenly has been added travels around the circuit at almost the speed of light. The voltage across the 100 Ohm resistor will almost _instantly_ drop even before any electrons have moved as far as a micrometer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That's where I get a little confused - what is that "news" physically? Is it a shift in the electric field? Or is it just a consequence of how voltage is defined?

Comment: Read what "transmission line effects" are. There are transitory periods, brief though they may be, where things are in flux where changes are propagated across the circuit, where "information" is conveyed before reaching steady state values.

Comment: @Basil The water-in-a-pipe analogy is a pretty good way to get your head around current flow.  If you put a restriction in a pipe somewhere, how does the water upstream "know" to flow more slowly?  And how does the water downstream "know" that it's got lower water pressure?  Obviously the analogy falls over in various ways, because it's only an analogy, but it's still a good way to get the hang of it.

Comment: They don't, but eventually (after a few nanoseconds) they reach an equilibrium where they do.

Comment: This YouTube video, imo, does a decent job of explaining how the current is 'determined' using concepts available in high school physics courses: https://youtu.be/tmD4MpSSqnk?si=8uOnx3svyEozrZsR

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7936/2451

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is communicated to the current through surface charges on the surface of conductors and at the interface between conductors of different conductivities.

So, for example, consider a circuit consisting of a battery and a single resistor of low conductivity, connected by wires of high conductivity. At the interface between the positive wire and the resistor there are positive charges, and at the interface between the negative wire and the resistor there are negative charges. These positive and negative charges set up an E field within the resistor, which drives the current at each point in the resistor.

Now, add a second identical resistor, directly attached to the first. Since there is no change in conductivity there is no surface charge between the two, and now the surface charges from the positive and negative wires are further apart. This reduces the E field and thereby reduces the current compared to the previous circuit.

Other more complicated circuits become rapidly more complicated to analyze, but the principle holds. It is the surface charges and their associated fields that communicate this information. This communication, of course, happens at the speed of light or slower during the transitory before the approximations of circuit theory become valid.

Comment: It may be helpful to mention that at the circuit level the transitory period where information about changes are propagated across the circuit results in transmission line effects. The steady state voltage drops across components do not just come into being instantaneously.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for the suggestion! I have added a sentence to that effect

Answer (score 11):

Once you accept circuit theory, then things must work as the theory describe. It is still a valid question to ask why is circuit theory true and why circuit theory is apparently non local.

Given there is no capacitor in a region of the circuit diagram, total current-in equals total current-out in the region. This is a non local rule that is not true in the smallest time scale but is approximately true on the time scale of typical circuit dynamics. At the shortest time scale when the switch just turns on, all charge carries don't care about the global environment. However, those electron accumulates at different points of the circuit and quickly reach some partial steady state that satisfy this non local rule about current. This non local in-out current rule is the reason why resistors can allocate voltage while "considering" other resisters in the circuit.

By the way, most rules in circuit theory are non local and are violated at very short time scale.

Answer (score 8):

Anthropomorphizing the physics in this case has made your problem far weirder than necessary. The fact that you have different resistances means there is different current flow for a given voltage. It is like a bottleneck in the flow of electrons. No knowledge is required: the electrons are just trying to move and in some regions it is harder to do so.

Comment: This is not a helpful perspective, in my opinion - it's perfectly valid to ask how the circuit establishes equilibrium at the local, microscopic level.

Comment: It's really hard to avoid anthropomorphizing, e.g. "trying to move".

Comment: Ha, I completely agree! And I don’t even discourage it. It is just sometimes helpful to step back and see whether we are confusing ourselves by assigning or looking for agency where there is none.